# Могу ли я создавать элементы визуального интерфейса в MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Могу ли я создавать элементы визуального интерфейса в MVVM? Допустим у меня по нажатию кнопки "+" появляется еще один TextBox. Как это прописать во VM?

Comment: Сделайте коллекцию VM, который содержит в себе все необходимое `TextBox`'a и привяжите ее к `ItemsControl` (или что то на его основе) с нужным стилем.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так мне же всё равно придётся в коде создавать TextBox-ы

Comment: Почему в коде? В коде у вас будет просто `class MySuperViewModel { public string Text {get;set} }` и коллекция `public ObservableCollection<MySuperViewModel> Items {get;set}`. Как видите нету работы напрямую с контролами, ибо им место только в View слое. А в XAML пишем `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"><ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>наш текстбокс, который привязывает нужные свойства из MySuperViewModel</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate></ItemsControl>`.